# Very slow start up

Tags: swap

I am using the following release:

```
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

I am having problems with my start up, it is very slow about 1 minute. When I look `dmesg` there is a jump from 1.8 seconds to 38.5 seconds. The message is:

```
[    1.779992]  sdc: sdc1
[    1.780309] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[   38.547971] Adding 8386556k swap on /dev/sdb5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8386556k 
[   38.554197] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

If I am understanding `dmesg` information, there is a problem with swap on `/dev/sdb5`
Is it true?
What can I do to correct this situation?

Curiously my system never use swap partition because I have a lot of memory, look this information!:

```
hugo@hugo-P35-DS3L:~$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8177232    1370480    6806752          0       2576     277356
-/+ buffers/cache:    1090548    7086684
Swap:      8386556          0    8386556
```

Can you help me?

Comment: It could also be networking. Try a [bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) (installable with `apt`).